# Margin in LaTeX-Report alternating / Page number not centered

Tags: numbering, margins, geometry

I'm just preparing a LaTeX document for a research paper and have two problems with the formatting:

1. I'd like to have a margin of 4cm from the left and the top and of 2cm from the right and the bottom. Surprisingly (for me) the margins are alternating from page to page.
2. I tried to place the page numbers into the footer and would like them to be centered. Nonetheless they seem to be shifted a little bit to the sides.

Here's my example code:

```
\documentclass[report]{apa7}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{literatur/literatur.bib}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}    

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=40mm,
 right=20mm,
 bottom=20mm,
 top=40mm
 }

\let\llncssubparagraph\subparagraph
\let\subparagraph\paragraph
\usepackage[up,bf,raggedright]{titlesec}
\let\subparagraph\llncssubparagraph
 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{white}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{titlepage}
    \newgeometry{left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm}
    \begin{center}
    \vspace{.5cm}
        \begin{Large}\textbf{University}\end{Large}\\
    \vspace{.5cm}
        \begin{Large}Section\end{Large}\\
        \vspace{2cm}
    \begin{Large}\textbf{Thesis}\end{Large}\\
    \vspace{.5cm}
    Course
        \vspace{2cm}
        Course\\
        \large{\textbf{Title}}\\
        \vspace{2cm}
        Topic\\
    \vspace{0.5cm}
        \large{\textbf{Title}}\\
        \vspace{2cm}
    von\\
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \begin{Large}{Author}\end{Large}\\
    \end{center}
    \normalsize
    \vfill
    \begin{tabular}{ l l }
        Betreuer: & Name\\
        Matrikelnummer: & Number\\
        Abgabedatum: & \today
    \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{titlepage}

\newpage

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\enlargethispage{-20mm}}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\tableofcontents 

\newpage
\section{Chapter 1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\newpage
\section{Chapter 2}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\printbibliography[nottype=online,heading=bibintoc,title={Literaturverzeichnis}]


\end{document}
```

Has anyone of you an idea how to fix these two problems?

Thanks in advance for your support
Florian

Comment: I assume this is **not** for publication.  [oneside] for apa7 **should** fix the odd/even thing.  `\pagestyle{plain}` should center the page numbers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Looks like you have a two-side document (which means that "left" and "right" pages are distinguished). In this case, the "left"-key of geometry corresponds to the inner margin, and the "right"-key to the outer margin (see https://texdoc.org/serve/geometry.pdf/0, Section 5.4). The fact you have a two-side document probably comes from your documentclass.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, really appreciate that!

@JohnKormylo: Can you explain to me why you mention this not being for publication?

I tried `\pagestyle{plain}` and it works fine, thanks for that one. Using `\documentclass[oneside]{apa7}` unfortunately doesn't change the alternating margins. It still seems to be a two-side document.

Comment: It is not a good idea to change the formatting provided by a class if the result is to be published. Classes like `apa7` are provided to give the typeset result that the publishers are after, and they may well discard anything else. I realise that you can make LaTeX produce any typeset result you want but think long and hard before changing anything like the results of the `apa7` document, and then don't do it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, Peter. That sounds logical and is really helpful!